# SSRS Site Hosting and URL Masking

Tags: html, ssrs-2008, frames, html-frames

I'm planning to host a frame web page on a SSRS Report Server, from where users will be able to access the page using the URL similar to the one as follows:

```
 https:\\server\ReportServer?%2fWeb+Page%2fMainFrame.html&rs:Command=GetResourceContents
```

All the other html pages, images, and reports that the website use are stored in the same path on the Report Server.  I was wondering if this itself was an acceptable practice, and would also like to explore the capabilities of URL masking.  This is complex because the reports also have objects that allow users to navigate in the web page by using the 'Go to URL' action, with hard-coded URL strings like the one above.  The Report Server URL is hence exposed when a user hovers their mouse over a link or an object.  Does anyone know a work-around?  An ASP.net solution is out of the question and beyond what I can do due to outside constraints.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use relative links for images in a folder on the report server. The only problem with that is that the images don't show during design previews, only when the report is uploaded and the path is relevant.

Comment: This is not ideal but you can use a js calls in 'Go To Url' navigation link, however that tightly couples your report to the given application.